# How to change the color (e.g., with Inkscape) of a scatter plot made with pyplot and exported in .svg?

Tags: matplotlib, svg, scatter-plot, inkscape

I like to export my plots in .svg and to tweak colors, etc. using a svg editor after a while.
I can change the color of most elements but I cannot change the color (or line width) of markers in a scatter plot using Inkscape as I normally do.

python code would be

```py
pl.scatter(data_x, data_y, color='C0', marker='+')
# or pl.plot(data_x, data_y, '+')
pl.savefig('myplot.svg')
```

The .svg part that matters is something like

```xml
<g
     id="line2d_19"
     style="stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:round">
    <defs
       id="defs329">
      <path
         d="M -3,0 H 3 M 0,3 v -6"
         id="mf156d26074"
         style="stroke:#1f77b4;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:round"
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
    </defs>
    <g
       clip-path="url(#p3979103b39)"
       id="g337"
       style="stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:round">
      <use
         style="fill:#1f77b4;stroke:#1f77b4;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:round"
         x="73.832726"
         xlink:href="#mf156d26074"
         y="295.48801"
         id="use331"
         width="100%"
         height="100%" />
<!-- 
    ...
-->
      <use
         style="fill:#1f77b4;stroke:#1f77b4;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:round"
         x="236.16"
         xlink:href="#mf156d26074"
         y="53.568001"
         id="use333"
         width="100%"
         height="100%" />

    </g>
  </g>
```

matplotlib version: 3.1.3

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I figured out one solution which is to delete the style tag in the definition of the `mf156d26074` path object beforehand with a text editor.

so to go from

```xml
    <defs
       id="defs329">
      <path
         d="M -3,0 H 3 M 0,3 v -6"
         id="mf156d26074"
         style="stroke:#1f77b4;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:round"
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
    </defs>
```

to

```xml
    <defs
       id="defs329">
      <path
         d="M -3,0 H 3 M 0,3 v -6"
         id="mf156d26074"
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
    </defs>
```

Afterwards, everything works as expected.